# Proxies and ARC, incompatible?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to implement proxies for database stored procedures. The idea is to have my code find a series of stored procedures in the database, then create a proxy object in memory which will implement methods matching those stored procedures. That proxy object could be derived from NSProxy or NSObject, both should work. The basic idea is that any method calls made to my proxy object would go to resolveInstanceMethod: and be handled there if the method call matched a stored procedure in the database.

But before even getting close to my objective, I'm stumped by ARC seemingly not allowing me to do method calls to undeclared methods. Back in the days before ARC, we got a warning like "object may not respond to selector" from the compiler and that was that, but with ARC enabled, I'm getting a compiler error saying "no known instance method for selector...". This also happens if I first cast the proxy object to (id).

This all seems to imply that ARC is incompatible with runtime discovery of methods, which is one of the fundamental characteristics of objective-c. It seems to mandate that all methods used must be declared in interfaces before compilation, just as in C++.

Or, more likely, I'm missing something essential. If so, what?

Edited to include code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");


    MyTargetClass *mtc = [[MyTargetClass alloc] init];
    [mtc doSomething];
}
return 0;
}
```

MyTargetClass contains nothing:

```
@interface MyTargetClass : NSObject

@end
```

The [mtc doSomething] call elicits a warning if in a non-ARC project, but elicits a compiler error with ARC. IMHO that means I can't add methods to a class in runtime if ARC is used.

Answer (score 0):

mwehlou,

First, if you don't show us any code, then it is really hard to help you.

Second, if you know that you will provide the instance method, then you can silence the warnings with the following `#pragma`s:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"

[Your Selector Based Code Here]

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

If that is the warning symbol, well, you can probably find it from within your build settings in Xcode.

Andrew

Comment: I added code to the question, but as you see, the code is 100% trivial. The problem is that what is a warning under non-ARC and can be suppressed by your pragma is an outright error if ARC is used.

Comment: Nothing precludes you dynamically adding methods to an object in ARC projects. The compiler is objecting to your lack of defined method. Traditionally, this is handled with a -performSelector:withObject: message. ARC needs to know the naming convention used in the method and whether it returns a value. (Yes, I know the compiler could infer these types from how you use them but Apple has chosen not to do so.)

Comment: mwhelou, I am wondering why it is important for you to add methods without a header? The warning on non-ARC code is indicative that you are entering a corner case of Objective-C. As there is an almost trivial fix, why is the use of undefined messages useful? Also, you can turn ARC off on a per file basis. Use -fno-objc-arc on the file in your build phases. Andrew

Comment: The idea was to create a proxy object for database stored procedures on the fly. The methods would be added according to which procedures are found in the database. The "performSelector" would be really ugly, since these stored procedures can have a number of arguments of different types. -- Martin